# C#でExcelの条件付き書式を指定したいです。

Tags: c#, vba

c#で既に作られたExcelファイルを開き、一定の範囲を指定して、
条件付き書式を利用して空白のセルを「黄色」に表示したいですが、

```
Excel.Range range = sheet.get_Range(一定の範囲);
range.FormatConditions.Add(Excel.XlFormatConditionType.xlBlanksCondition);
range.Interior.ColorIndex = ExcelColorIndex.Yellow;
```

上記のコードで実行してみた結果、
条件付き書式の書式で「黄色」が指定されるのではなく
ただ範囲全体が塗り替える結果が出ました。

vbaのようにwithを利用しても`range.FormatConditions.Add(Excel.XlFormatConditionType.xlBlanksCondition).Interior.ColorIndex = 27`
を利用してもエラーが出ました。

条件付き書式の書式を「黄色」に設定する方法を教えていただけますでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

`Excel.Range`(範囲全体)に対して塗り替えるコードになっているのが原因です。
`Excel.FormatCondition`(条件付き書式の書式)に対して塗り替えるように見直してください。
`range.FormatConditions.Add`の戻り値として`Excel.FormatCondition`が返ってきますので、下記のコードのように記述するとうまく行くはずです。

```
using System;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // ToDo 読み取り先ファイルパスに書きなおす
            string file = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "Book1.xlsx");

            Excel.Application app = new Excel.Application();
            Excel.Workbook book = app.Workbooks.Open(file);
            try
            {
                Excel.Worksheet sheet = book.Worksheets[1];
                Excel.Range range = sheet.Range["A1", "B2"];

                // 条件付き書式の書式を変数に格納
                Excel.FormatCondition condition = range.FormatConditions.Add(Excel.XlFormatConditionType.xlBlanksCondition);
                // 書式のColorIndexを指定する
                condition.Interior.ColorIndex = 27;

                book.Save();
            }
            finally
            {
                book.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

後半のコードはvbaでwithを利用したのでしょうか？
変数名が`range`になっていて意図しないエラーが発生しているかもしれません。
vbaで下記のコードを実行したところ正常に動作しました。

```
Sub ボタン1_Click()
    Dim rng As range
    Set rng = range("A1:B2")
    rng.FormatConditions.Add(Excel.XlFormatConditionType.xlBlanksCondition).Interior.ColorIndex = 27
End Sub
```

`rng`変数を`range`変数に変更した場合は下記のエラーが発生します。

```
実行時エラー'91':
オブジェクト変数または With ブロック変数が設定されていません。
```